# Dlang operator overloading =

Tags: operator-overloading, d

How i can use = operator overloading in a class in order to assign a value ??

```
int[4] users;
int someop(string op)(int j){
    if(op == "="){
       //example
       users[j] = j
      }
}
```

Comment: *Can* the assignment operator be overloaded, per the documentation? Even in languages with overload support, generalized assignment is often "special".

Comment: Oh, that's cute - also it's own section in *existing documentation*: https://dlang.org/spec/operatoroverloading.html#assignment : "The assignment operator = can be overloaded *if [and only if]* the left hand side is a struct aggregate, and opAssign is a member function of that aggregate." There are also index/slice operator overloading.. anyway. So, coffee and TFM should be utilized first..

Comment: ..which also clearly indicates that for `opOpAssign`, it's only the *compound* assignments that are supported. Going back to the original hypothesis presented: assignment overloading is "special".

Answer (score 3):

It is all in the documentation - https://dlang.org/spec/operatoroverloading.html#assignment ...

For details on how to overload other operators refer to the "[Operator Overloading](https://dlang.org/spec/operatoroverloading.html)" section of the D Language Specification.